# Connecting angular-formly to Django

Tags: python, django, angular-formly

I am trying to create a web application using Angular-formly on the front end and a Django framework on the back end. Have a couple of questions regarding this:

1. How do I send data from angular-formly form to Django and there on to mysql database and vice versa? The following is part of my code

   ```
   {
   key: 'Rate',
   type: 'input',
   templateOptions: {
            label: 'Enter Cost!',
            type: 'text',
         }
   }
   ```

   How can I access this rate value in my Django code ?
2. How do I create a file upload button using angular formly.

Thank you

Comment: May be this post may be of some orientation support  https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/file-upload-with-angular/

Comment: There is some series of Angular  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wc8Gv8X49U&list=PLEsfXFp6DpzQThMU768hTZInWUqfoyTEW and